# How to write Text in different colors in single word in win2d Canvas windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win2d

[image]I use in xaml RichTextbox paragraph and run element with different color and Font Style.
how to add on this control in win2d Canvas and move in canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the CanvasTextLayout class, in particular its SetColor method.